# Rails #classify strange output

Tags: ruby-on-rails

using rails 3.0.1 and ruby 1.9.2-p0

in the rails console I'm seeing the following:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "login_controller".classify
 => "LoginController"

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > {:controller=>"login", :action=>"show"}[:controller]+"_controller".classify
 => "login_controller" 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "login_controller" == {:controller=>"login", :action=>"show"}[:controller]+"_controller"
 => true
```

Why is `classify` returning 'login_controller' for the one, and 'LoginController" for the other, when ruby says both strings are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your order of operations isn't right. In the second example, the implicit brackets are going like this:

```
{:controller=>"login", :action=>"show"}[:controller] + ("_controller".classify)
```

since `.` binds before `+`. To fix it, you can do this:

```
({:controller=>"login", :action=>"show"}[:controller] + "_controller").classify
```

ie, include the brackets yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Never fails,

It's operator precedence.  I need to do:

```
({:controller=>"login", :action=>"show"}[:controller]+"_controller").classify
```